# Matlab syms variable precision?

Tags: matlab, variables, precision, symbolic-math, arithmetic-expressions

Just having some issues with variable precision in matlab..

I have the code:

```
x = 0.1;
syms y;
S = solve(x+1==(1+y)/(1-y),y);
y = double(S);
val = abs(((2^2)*(y^2))/(2*(y-1)^2))
```

But val is always rounded off.
I should be getting `val = 0.0049999` but instead I am getting `val = 0.0050`.

Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding extra code

```
x = 0.1;
syms y;
S = solve(x+1==(1+y)/(1-y),y);
y = double(S);
val = abs(((2^2)*(y^2))/(2*(y-1)^2))
sprintf('%22.20f',val)

for i=1:2
    val= val+((2^i)*(y^i))/(i*(y-1)^i);
    sprintf('%22.20f',val)
end
```

The first sprintf works and shows correct rounding, however the second doesnt!!

Comment: How do `N` and `i` relate in your additional code?

Comment: Sorry, the `N` is meant to be an `i`!

Comment: What output do you expect? I get `0.00499999999999999924`, `-0.09500000000000000111` and `-0.08999999999999999667`

Comment: I'm getting rounded values, specifically `0.10`. I took my code out of the loop and found an issue. If I have `if abs(val-1) == 1` followed by a `break;` and `end`, I get the rounding issues. Otherwise not. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you get the `0.1`? Additionally, what do you need these numbers for?

Comment: Just for testing. I found the issue. If I set `val = 0;` before the loop, I will get rounding issues. If not, it will go smoothly. Any idea why out of curiosity? Thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36737/discussion-between-schorsch-and-travv92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the [floating-point representation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and how [Matlab displays such numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#bqxyrhp) for readability. If you add this line to the end of your code:

```
sprintf('%22.20f',val)
```

you'll get:

```
ans =

0.00499999999999999924
```

**Edit**
Even though it technically deals with Python, [this website](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) offers a brief and concise overview on the limitations of floating-point representations.

Comment: Does it only look rounded because of the way it formats the integer for printing? The code I posted is just a small snippet and the actual functions are in a loop. If I put your print above the loop, it works. However inside the loop I am still getting rounding issues... I will post the code in the OP now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you merely set your preferences for displaying numbers to short rather than long?  It would help if you eliminated that as a possibility.